# Use a button to input value in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, button

I am looking to use an onclick button function in JQuery which when clicked returns the value in the button to the text area of a form. So for example I am building a calculator when i click 1 , 1 should be the value in the form input area. Any clues how i can do that?

```
<FORM NAME="Calc">
<TABLE BORDER=4>
<TR>
<TD>
<INPUT id ="enter" TYPE="text" NAME="Input" Size="16">
<br>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<button type ="submit" NAME="one" value="1"> 1 </button>
```

Comment: Goog: "JavaScript How to get input value  on click" ...

Answer (score 0):

First brush up the basics of language

```
<button class="btncalc" value="1" type="button"></button>
$('.btncalc').click(function(){
    $'#enter').val($(this).val());
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="">
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>

<script>
 $( "button" ).click(function() {
  var current = $("input").text();
  var update = $( this ).text();
  $("input").val( current + update );
 });
</script>
```

I would avoid using `<button type ="submit" NAME="one" value="1"> 1 </button>` for your inputs in your calculator because this will cause a full form post due to type ="submit".

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html

I grabbed most of the code from here (3/4 down the page). This will give you a feel for how it will work.

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Sounds like fun I hope it turns out nice :)